# Which paperboard/wood is not healthy for cooking barbecue?

Tags: paper, cooking, firewood, cardboard

In Argentina on weekends we cook barbecue with fire generated with woods and paperboard. We don't use gas like in the USA. I know there are some things that cause cancer and other illness like OSB wood because it has glues. So I would like to know which wood, paperboard, paper, etc. is not healthy. I'm thinking about painted paper.

Comment: Hi robysottini, and welcome. Please can you clarify how your question is about sustainability? You can edit the quesiton by using the "edit" link underneath it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not directly related to sustainability.

Comment: Why not?  The question is about (dangerous, imo) practices to keep cooking techniques more sustainable--using replaceable fuels instead of fossil fuels.  Identifying bad fuels to use for cooking is totally on topic.